# No answer link present on question

Tags: discussion

I am a new user. I have created a password, so that my account (user3562230) is
setup. I am able to look at the profile page and add a note there.

However, when I look at a particular question, **I don't see a button to answer
the question.** **This question has been marked as a duplicate,** but there are
errors in the answers present in that page.

I wanted to add an answer, pointing out the mistakes in couple of answers. There
is no "ANSWER" button or a link that I can see. My reputation is only 1 as new
user, so I can not add a comment.

Comment: Are the linked answers erroneous too?

Comment: No, the linked answers are ok. The one marked as duplicator would have the error, in case someone reads only that question, without bothering to go to the link given at top. I will add my comments in the thread that is "NOT" marked as duplicate.

Comment: Please be aware that the answers can and do change their order though.

Comment: @user3562230 the easy way to solve your problem is to collect some reputation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Questions that are closed as duplicates of another cannot be answered. This is to encourage answering on the target canonical question.

If there are problems with the answer on the target question, feel free to leave a correct answer on the original question.

Comment: what about the errors that still exist? He asked if he could somehow correct those.

Comment: I read "there are errors in the answers present in that page" as referring to answers on the target question. Maybe I interpreted that incorrectly.

Comment: I understand Brad's  answer. The question that has been marked as duplicate can not be answered - so the only way to correct the errors in it, is by answering the other question (the link to this one is given at top of the question that has been marked as duplicate).

Comment: @user3562230 can you please provide a link to the question that you're talking about, or provide its title if a link is not possible?

Comment: @user3562230 In addition to what was said in this answer, it's worth noting that answers should only attempt to answer the question. If you just wish to point out a mistake in another answer, you should use the comments for that instead (although you need a bit more reputation for commenting). If [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236/how-do-you-determine-the-size-of-a-file-in-c/23328825#23328825) is what you're talking about, a comment on the one 'correct' answer might be appropriate, along with upvotes and/or downvotes where you feel it's appropriate (which also need a bit more rep).